# Using OpenCSV to extract specific numbers from CSV

Tags: java, csv, opencsv, aiml

I have CSV files with headers and specific numbers. I need to extract those numbers individually to create a AIM XML file with, but that's not important. I'm having a hard time trying to extract the numbers based on the their headers. I've tried various things but couldn't get it to work. When I try to run this code (below is just a sampling), it never seems to terminate. I'm not very experienced with Java or OpenCSV, so please excuse the mess you are about to see. (it's also 2AM and my mind is malfunctioning)

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import edu.stanford.hakan.aim3api.base.AimException;
import edu.stanford.hakan.aim3api.base.ImageAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.hakan.aim3api.usage.AnnotationBuilder;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;



public class CreateAIMFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException,     AimException
{
    ImageAnnotation PeserAnnotation1 = new ImageAnnotation ();
    String csvFilename = "C:/Users/Daniela/Documents/ISPY/205_4493_MR1_ACRIN_6657/E25008/peser_data.csv"; //Insert file name and location
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
    String [] nextLine = csvReader.readNext();

    //start 
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++){ //i<50 is a random number
        while (nextLine[i] != null){
            if (nextLine[i] == "CagridId") //customize name
            {
                CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ';', '\'', 1);
                Integer A = Integer.valueOf(nextLine[i]);
                PeserAnnotation1.setCagridId(A); 
            }
            else
            {
            PeserAnnotation1.setCagridId(0); 
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++){ 
        while (nextLine[i] != null){
            if (nextLine[i] == "PatientComment") //customize name
            {
                CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ';', '\'', 1);
                PeserAnnotation1.setComment(nextLine[i]); 
            }
        else
            {
                PeserAnnotation1.setComment("");
            }
        }
    }
AnnotationBuilder.saveToFile(PeserAnnotation1, "./AIMFileName.xml", "AIM_v3.xsd");     //customize name of XML file
    System.out.println(AnnotationBuilder.getAimXMLsaveResult());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing csvReader.readNext(); with csvReader.readAll();

Try this (not compiled!):

```
String headerLine = csvReader.readNext();

List numbersInHeader = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0 ; i < headerLine.length ; i++){
    if(headerLine[i].equals("YouHeaderNameHere") || headerLine[i].equals("OtherNumberHeader")){
        numberInHeader.add(i);
    } 
}
String line[] = null;
while((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < line.length ; i++){
        if(numbersInHeader.contains(i)){ 
            // This is a number do you work here

        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one will open the CSV file once by instantiating a CSVReader object and then loop through the file calling readNext.

In your code you are re-instantiating the CSVReader in the loop and not calling readNext in your loop.